# Eclipse PDE: Custom QuickFix only available in Problems View?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-pde, markers

i am having trouble with custom quick-fixes, which i want to provide in my Eclipse plug-in, and i'm hoping for someone more experienced than me in Eclipse PDE to have some hints for me on this issue.

As i have understood, i can provide custom so-called "quick fixes" (or "resolutions", in Eclipse inside terminology), by extending the extension point *org.eclipse.ui.ide.markerResolution* for a specific marker id, such as for example some default Eclipse marker, *org.eclipse.core.resources.problemmarker*.

This works for me for the default marker types and for custom marker types, **BUT**:
The QuickFixes, which my *IMarkerResolutionGenerator* provides, are only accessible from the "Problems"-View, not from the Editor, in which my markers show up.

**What i have**: I create markers in the default text editor, which causes (1) an icon with the markers tooltip message to show up on the left editor ruler at the line, which the marker is assigned to, (2) a marker on the right side of the editor, (3) some underlined characters in the editor, and (4) an entry in the "Problems"-view.

**What i want**: Just like in Java IDE support, i want to press Strg+1, or Context-Menu->Quick Fix, or to click at the error icon on the left-side-ruler, to see the available quick-fixes and to select one.

**However**: Only in the Problems-View am i able to get the Quick-Fixes, by pressing Strg+1 or from the context menu.

Is this the normal behaviour, and do i have to access another extension point, or the specific editors features, to hook my quick fixes into them? I haven't found anything much detailed about it, except that everybody seems to be pretty happy with this only extension point that i have mentioned above. What am i missing?

For completion, here is my extension point definition:

```
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.ide.markerResolution">
    <markerResolutionGenerator
        class="com.markers.test.MarkerResolutionGenerator"
        markerType="org.eclipse.core.resources.problemmarker">
    </markerResolutionGenerator>
</extension>
```

Comment: I forgot to mention the most important: I am currently working with Eclipse Indigo SR1, a clean RCP&RAP distribution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have the same problem and I'm not sure, if this is the right way, but at least it works:

If you want to see your quick fixes in the source viewer you have to set an `QuickAssistAssistant` for it. In your class implementing `SourceViewerConfiguration` override `getQuickAssistAssistant`. You can instantiate `org.eclipse.jface.text.quickassist.QuickAssistAssistant`, but you have to set a `QuickAssistProcessor`, so implement the `org.eclipse.jface.text.quickassist.IQuickAssistProcessor` interface, especially `computeQuickAssistProposals` to return your quick fix proposals.

```
public IQuickAssistAssistant getQuickAssistAssistant(ISourceViewer sourceViewer) {
  IQuickAssistAssistant quickAssist = new QuickAssistAssistant();
  quickAssist.setQuickAssistProcessor(new MyQuickAssistProcessor());
  quickAssist.setInformationControlCreator(getInformationControlCreator(sourceViewer));
  return quickAssist; 
}
```

Also have a look at the code in the last post [here](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/334673/?srch=annotation%20marker%20problem%20view#msg_334673), it is a bit messy, but you will get it. And look at this code [here](http://javasourcecode.org/html/open-source/eclipse/eclipse-3.5.2/org/eclipse/jdt/internal/ui/text/correction/proposals/MarkerResolutionProposal.java.html) for an example implementation of `ICompletionProposal`, which you will have to return in your `QuickAssistProcessor`.

Comment: Thank you a lot, this will certainly lead me into the right direction! Just for now: It seems to be all about enriching a **custom Editor** with a **custom `SourceViewerConfiguration`**. Is it also possible to provide an _existing editor_ (such es text editor, XML editor) with a custom 'SourceViewerConfiguration'?

Comment: Just extend `org.eclipse.ui.editors.text.TextEditor` and use `setSourceViewerConfiguration(new MySourceViewerConfiguration(new ColorManager()));` to set your custom `SourceViewerConfiguration`.

But I don't know about the existing XML editor, maybe this link could help you: http://vzurczak.wordpress.com/2010/09/25/merge-compare-dialogs-and-xml-syntax-highlighting/

Answer (score 0):

If you simply add one line to the marker extension point:

```
<super type="org.eclipse.core.resources.textmarker"/>
```

and add attributes to the marker
    marker.setAttribute(IMarker.CHAR_START, ...);
    marker.setAttribute(IMarker.CHAR_END, ...);

You will be able get this:

[image: displayed quick fix as text hover]

But I still can't found how to change marker icon (to variant with bulb) a show possible quick fix also after click on the annotation icon.

Comment: I am able to get the bulb icon via annotation but not able to get the quickfix as shown in your screenshot.

can you please help me?

Comment: @shalin you may want to create your own question and to provide more information about your implementation.