# Eclipse PDE : How to add marker with quick action

Tags: eclipse, marker, pde

My problem is related to the: [Eclipse PDE: Custom QuickFix only available in Problems View?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8866688/eclipse-pde-custom-quickfix-only-available-in-problems-view), but I can't use QuickAssistAssistant. I need to add marker with quick fix to existing M2E pom.xml editor.

I'm already able do this:

[image: displayed quick fix as text hover]

But I still can't found how to change marker icon (to variant with bulb) a show possible quick fix also after click on the annotation icon.

I want this icon
[image: What I want]

I'm currently use this configuration

```
   <extension
          id="me.gladwell.eclipse.m2e.android.markers.dependency.apklib"
          point="org.eclipse.core.resources.markers">
          <super type="org.eclipse.core.resources.problemmarker"/>
          <super type="org.eclipse.core.resources.textmarker"/>
          <super type="me.gladwell.eclipse.m2e.android.markers.dependency"/>
          <persistent value="true" />
   </extension>
   <extension
           point="org.eclipse.ui.ide.markerResolution">
           <markerResolutionGenerator
                  markerType="me.gladwell.eclipse.m2e.android.markers.dependency.apklib"
                  class="me.gladwell.eclipse.m2e.android.quickfix.ImportApklibResolutionGenerator"/>
   </extension>   
   <extension
           point="org.eclipse.ui.editors.annotationTypes">
           <type
               name="me.gladwell.eclipse.m2e.android.annotations"
               super="org.eclipse.ui.workbench.texteditor.error"
               markerType="me.gladwell.eclipse.m2e.android.markers.dependency.apklib"
               markerSeverity="2">
         </type>
   </extension>
```

Comment: Did you manage to solve the problem? Can you provide some code snippets? Thanks in advance.

Comment: No,  I stopped using Eclipse already.

Comment: But what about existing answer?  I'm not able decide if it is useful.

Comment: it is irrelevant. It explains only how to change marker's icon but not how to obtain quick fix proposals when clicking on marker's icon. It seems that to provide this functionality, a lot of code must be copied and adjusted from cdt or jdt.

Comment: I also wonder how did you manage to show fix proposals in hover window...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be I'm too late, but you need to check [org.eclipse.ui.workbench.texteditor.markerAnnotationSpecification](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/extension-points/org_eclipse_ui_workbench_texteditor_rulerColumns.html&resultof=%22RulerColumnDescriptor%22%20%22rulercolumndescriptor%22) extension point .

Just extend it with your annotationType and specify 'quickFixIcon' attribute with quickfix icon